# How do I access individual groups after using GroupBy on a Dataset object?

Tags: fitting, gathering

I want to read in an xlsx (Excel) or TSV (tab-delimited) file, assuming this 
results in a  rectangular table of data. Then I after applying GroupBy (using 
multiple keys), I  should have several different groups of data though they are 
'stacked' on top of each other. How would I select each group, one at a time so 
that I can apply for example a Line or Curve fitting function to each of the groups and output results for each group?

```
raw= Import["C:\\STUFF.txt", "TSV"]
header = raw[[1]]
data = raw[[2 ;;]]
myDataset =  Thread[header -> #] & /@ data // Map[Association] // Dataset
```

This results in a standard database-like table of data. From here, how do I 
group this table by multiple columns (Ex: "gen","style","state","mode")
and then apply A Line or Curve fitting function to each group to find best fit parameters for each group?

This is data BEFORE Sorting :

```
{{"", "attrib1", "attrib2", "attrib3", "var1", "var2", "var3", 
  "targetValue"}, {1., "donner", "scrabble", "santa", 3.73664, 
  3.13719, 5.45106, 8.5}, {2., "rudolf", "marbles", "grinch", 
  0.774004, 1.33989, 1.68732, 6.9}, {3., "blitzen", "marbles", 
  "grinch", 6.92852, 7.57531, 5.03245, 8.6}, {4., "rudolf", "marbles",
   "santa", 3.88404, 1.95399, 4.92164, 7.6}, {5., "donner", "marbles",
   "grinch", 0.65931, 6.87755, 1.82841, 10.3}, {6., "blitzen", 
  "marbles", "grinch", 3.95726, 1.24112, 1.40049, 9.4}, {7., "donner",
   "scrabble", "santa", 2.29372, 6.97873, 4.71533, 7.8}, {8., 
  "blitzen", "scrabble", "santa", 1.84786, 0.286934, 3.4215, 
  9.3}, {9., "rudolf", "scrabble", "grinch", 5.54639, 4.69658, 3.6046,
   7.5}, {10., "donner", "marbles", "grinch", 3.22634, 9.54838, 
  4.8924, 10.6}, {11., "blitzen", "scrabble", "santa", 3.38442, 
  0.910412, 2.23809, 8.7}, {12., "rudolf", "scrabble", "santa", 
  7.71931, 2.41088, 3.59705, 9.9}}
```

How do I get to The following Table (grouped by All 3 vars in Mathematica)

```
{{"", "attrib1", "attrib2", "attrib3", "var1", "var2", "var3", 
  "targetValue"}, {1., "blitzen", "marbles", "grinch", 0.324634, 
  5.55465, 7.33444, 8.6}, {2., "blitzen", "marbles", "grinch", 
  4.68461, 0.621629, 5.45658, 9.4}, {3., "blitzen", "scrabble", 
  "santa", 0.321507, 2.40429, 2.35555, 9.3}, {4., "blitzen", 
  "scrabble", "santa", 6.78552, 0.691274, 6.69245, 8.7}, {5., 
  "donner", "marbles", "grinch", 1.58886, 4.88366, 7.42987, 
  10.3}, {6., "donner", "marbles", "grinch", 4.33855, 8.9008, 0.88771,
   10.6}, {7., "donner", "scrabble", "santa", 2.33365, 8.39023, 
  5.03501, 8.5}, {8., "donner", "scrabble", "santa", 3.0631, 3.81142, 
  3.34073, 7.8}, {9., "rudolf", "marbles", "grinch", 0.483345, 
  4.90253, 6.51428, 6.9}, {10., "rudolf", "marbles", "santa", 5.84364,
   4.42051, 4.11002, 7.6}, {11., "rudolf", "scrabble", "grinch", 
  0.408628, 0.84849, 0.979443, 7.5}, {12., "rudolf", "scrabble", 
  "santa", 8.83514, 0.326181, 7.61163, 9.9}}
```

Now, How do I get to table 2 from table 1, THEN, get the Multipliers of var 1,2 and 3 for each GROUP to Predict targetValue for that GROUP?

So now each 'group' consists of all rows that have the same value for all three vars (1,2 and3)
FINAL RESULT : to predict targetValue of, for example, the blitzen-marbles-grinch group , the multipliers are : (3.4 * var1) + (.87 * var2) - (.06 * var3) = (PREDICTED targetValue) OR for the donner-scrabble-santa group , the multipliers are : (2.7 * var1) + (.91 * var2) - (.26 * var3) = (PREDICTED targetValue)
I need the Function(s) that give me the 3.4, .87 .06 (or the 2.7, .91, .26) whether a linear or non-linear Function, whichever may apply.
Finally, what references (web,Book,blog etc) cover this type of analysis and Data Analysis in general using Mathematica ? Thanks in Advance.

Comment: "From here, how do I group this table by multiple columns (Ex: "gen","style","state","mode")" seems ambiguous/vague. Can you provide an example of the sort of output you are seeking?

Comment: Could you put the example data in a form that we can copy and paste; that makes it a lot easier to answer your questions. myDataset//Normal will do what's needed and then paste into your question. Then we can give you some direction.

Answer (score 1):

I think the best way to convert the "before" data would look like this, assuming that the data list above is set to *raw*, and both *header* and *data* are defined as above:

```
ds1 = AssociationThread[header -> #] & /@ data // Dataset
```

This can then be grouped as follows:

```
ds2 = ds1[GroupBy["attrib1"],GroupBy["attrib2"],GroupBy["attrib3"]]
```

Which produces this dataset:

[image]

Extracting the data from this is a little complicated, and the best I have come up with is to do something like this (to extract the first set of data):

```
KeyTake[Values[ds2[1][1]]//Normal//Flatten,{"var1", "var2","var3", "targetValue"}]
```

Which gives:

> {<|"var1" -> 3.73664, "var2" -> 3.13719, "var3" -> 5.45106, 
>     "targetValue" -> 8.5|>, <|"var1" -> 2.29372, "var2" -> 6.97873, 
>     "var3" -> 4.71533, "targetValue" -> 7.8|>}

Another approach would be to construct the list of unique tuples that you want to look at, and then sort them:

```
vL = DeleteDuplicates[Values[KeyTake[ds1,{"attrib1","attrib2","attrib3"}]]]//Normal
vL = Sort[vL]
```

Producing:

> {{"blitzen", "marbles", "grinch"}, {"blitzen", "scrabble",
>   "santa"}, {"donner", "marbles", "grinch"}, {"donner", "scrabble",
>   "santa"}, {"rudolf", "marbles", "grinch"}, {"rudolf", "marbles",
>   "santa"}, {"rudolf", "scrabble", "grinch"}, {"rudolf", "scrabble",
>   "santa"}}

Then this function can extract any one of the unique tuples:

```
getValues[qL_, ds1_] :=
 Module[{},
  Query[Select[#attrib1 == qL[[1]] && 
       #attrib2 == qL[[2]] && 
       #attrib3 == qL[[3]] &], 
       {"attrib1", "attrib2", "attrib3", 
        "var1", "var2", "var3", "targetValue"}]@ds1
  ]
```

You can choose any of the elements of *vL* that interest you or all of them like this:

```
getValues[#, ds1] & /@ vL
```

The resulting dataset for any one value looks like this:

[image]

Which can then be converted to a list through Normal and Values and passed to your regression routine or whatever you wish.